# innerHTML after an img tag javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I'm trying to insert a variable after an img tag.

HTML :

```
<div id="cookie"><img src="cookie.png" />0</div>
```

JS :

```
var cookie = 0;
document.getElementById('cookie').fistChild.innerHTML = cookie;
```

It's doesn't work.
Can you help me ?
Thanks !

Comment: You spelled `firstChild` without the "r", but in any case the first child is the img element, for which you can't set inner html.

Answer (score 1):

You code (assuming no spelling mistakes) would try to the set the content of the image element itself. Since image elements don't have any content, you cannot do that.

Instead, create a new element and append it after the `img` element:

```
var content = document.createElement('span');
content.innerHTML = cookie;
var parent = document.getElementById('cookie');
parent.insertBefore(content, parent.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will overwrite the inner HTML so you have to save what's there first:

```
var cookie = 0;
var content = document.getElementById('cookie').innerHTML;

document.getElementById('cookie').innerHTML = content + cookie;
```

Comment: It's partially works, when i'm increment cookie, all numbers still here.
Ex : 0123456

Comment: then take the `content` var out of the incrementing scope so it's not overwritten

Comment: Can you give me an exemple?

Comment: I don't have the code where you are incrementing the cookie var

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
     document.getElementById('cookie').innerHTML = document.getElementById('cookie').innerHTML + cookie;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('cookie').childNodes[1].nodeValue = cookie;
```

text node value altered by `nodeValue` not by `innerHTML`.